# Name two reasons why the music in the next passage starts in C Major and ends in G major?

Tags: theory, chords, melody, analysis

[image: Score of analytical excerpt]

Please help with the question in the title. I am struggling so much, thank you.
Why?

Comment: Hi ANON. Welcome to Music Practice & Theory. Thanks for posting here. As a suggestion, you might wait a while before accepting an answer as others may weight in with additional information. In the meantime, it is certainly appropriate to upvote any answer you find helpful.

Comment: One way to analyze melodies and see how keys work is to look for the half steps. Try going through and marking all the places there is a half step in the music.

Comment: why _two_ reasons?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - it's a homework question. Those sort can ask what they want!

Comment: @Tim, anyone can ask anything anytime

Comment: I also think it´s a homework. And I think this isn‘t a good example. If this is a real composition the double bar line might assign the middle  between the 1st and 2nd section, like e.g. of a Suite or a Sonatina, but usually these parts ar repeated.

Answer (score 2):

The C major passage includes the C major leading tone (B) and emphasizes C major chord tones (C and E) by placing them in metrically strong locations (beats 1 and 2, and opposed to the Ds placed on the half-beats.)

Similarly, the G major passage includes the G major leading tone (F# -- which is not part of C major, thus suggesting a key change), and places G major chord tones (G and B) in metrically strong positions.

Comment: I'd argue that it ends **ON** G major rather than **IN** G major. Modulation rather than key change. Given that we don't know what precedes or follows - if any.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is pretty weak. `C` major as a key isn't really established. The main issue being the absence of the subdominant `F` natural. It's easy to hear the passage as a *conclusion* in `G` major outlining `G: IV V I`

Anyway, let's just say it moves from `C` major to `G` major. The question is why? And for some reason there needs to be *two* reasons.

1. Lots of music follows a convention of *periodic* phrasing where a first phrase ends on some kind of dominant harmony which is followed by a second phrase returning to the tonic chord. This passage is such an *antecedent* phrase.
2. The melody is a decoration of the tonic chord - the first beat of each bar outlines the tonic `C` chord `C4 E4 G4`. But the `G4` being the dominant of `C` major has a dual role where it can be considered a tone of the tonic *or* dominant chords. This passage could easily be modified to treat `G4` as a tone of the tonic `C` major chord. But it doesn't. Why? Another possibility, which may seems far-fetched, but you asked for two reasons, is an intension to use the line in *inverted counterpoint*. If the `G4` were treated as the fifth of a `C` major chord, and then it was inverted to be in the bass, you would have a dissonant fourth in the harmony, which is a type of counterpoint problem. That problem is avoided by treating `G4` to be the *root* of a `G` major chord, and inverting it into the bass won't be a problem.

Keep in mind you asked "why it starts in C and ends in G?" rather than something like "does this start in C and end in G?" Those are two very different questions - why versus is it? You are asking about *motivations*. In musical art you can do whatever you like any time you like. Reasons aren't necessarily required. My two suggested reasons are based on "classical" conventions.

Answer (score 1):

1. it may be a half cadence (G is the dominant of C) ... we expect a closing phrase ending on the tonic C: in this case the double bar sign (ending) wouldn‘t be correct.
2. the song is actually in G and you present the ending phrase: in this case we miss here an F# key-sign and the movable doremi-names are famifaso lasolati dosomire do

edit:

I assume this is a half close ending on the dominant key. There will follow another section leading back from G to C.

My answer is focussing the chord progression, while the question may ask why the first motif is in C and not G?

This is quite obvious: we have the key signature of C, the melody is on the accented beats on the C chord (with changing and passing tones. The F# shows the modulation to G, involving the triad dosomi of G.

Comment: Could it be a change in pitch? or not?

Comment: Given the double bar-line, a half-cadence seems unlikely.

Comment: No, the pitch doesn‘t  matter. If the F# would be F the secondary dominant D7 would be certainly  before the final G.

Comment: @Aaron: yes, then the answer will be: modulation to G but the double barline could still be a typo ...

Comment: If we allow for typos, then the answer could be anything at all.

Comment: Could it also be because there is an F#? C major does not have an F# ?

Comment: good point about the double barline!

Comment: Compare the French Suites by Bach: they usually have 2 sections: the 1st modulates to the dominant and is separated by a double bar line from the 2nd half of the piece, that continues with the dominant and leads back to the tonic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer your test paper is looking for will mention the F♯ and the way the melody comes to rest on G, implying a perfect cadence in that key. (Careful about naming cadences.  I'm using the British method.  You may need to call it an Authentic Cadence.)

Others have suggested that the visit to G major is too brief to be considered a change of key.  Maybe.  We don't know what comes before and after this brief extract.  But I've given an answer within the terms of the question.  It is generally unproductive to challenge the terms of this sort of question!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, it's just a cadence. Music needs to go somewhere, in Western music, that if frequently the dominant chord of the key you are in.

Answer (score -3):

Theres no.indication that the music indeed switches to G major .

F# is in C major as the #11th . This is a consonant sound for the Key of C major . Remember the F natural is  a Dominant  function in the Key of C major .

The simplest way to understand  why is the look at how all 12 notes fit into The KEY of C major

C is root of C major
C# is b5th of G7
D is 9th of Cmajor or 5th of G7
D# is b13th of G7
E is 3rd of C major
F is 7th of G7
F# is #11th of C major tonic
G is 5th of Cmajor or root of G7
G# is b9th of G7
A is 6th of C major or 9th of G7
A# is #9th of G7
B is 3rd of G7 or 7th of Cmaj
C is root of C major

Here is Key of C major how all 12 notes belong to the tonic or dominant functions.
( the subdominant combines notes of these 2 functions)

Now even after demonstrating this,  let's say you are are the Key of C major but you are unwilling to use any extensions .
It is still factually true that strong beats are chord tones and weak beats are any of the 12 notes .
In the above passage the F# is on a weak beat
( another reason why it does not leave the key of C major )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115617/discussion-between-mmj2020-and-aaron).

Answer (score -3):

A,G,A,D, E,D,E,F#,G,D,B,A,G

Its all Cmajor chord tonic
( play a Cmajor chord in bass register below the melody it never changes chords or functions )
Its a melody in the C major Key on the tonic function.